# Passing URL params to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following route

```
#routes.rb
resources :topic
```

And I'm trying to access the `:id` parameter from the URL `topic/1` in my controller

```
#controller/topic_controller.rb    
def show
    @param = params[:id]
end
```

to show it in `show.html.erb`

```
#view/show.html.erb
<div>
    <%= @param %>
</div>
```

However, nothing shows up and `@param` was not printed.

My `model/topic.rb` is as follows :

```
#model/topic.rb
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: The `show` file should be `#views/topic/show.html.erb` is that what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#routes.rb
resources :topics #plural
```

[Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

**UPDATED:**

```
#routes.rb
resources :topics #plural as per convention
```

Apparently it looks like your views path is not right. you need to add your `show` view in `views/topic/show.html.erb`

If you change the resources from `topic` to plural `topics` then you need to refactor your controller to `topics_controller`
Similarly your view path will be `views/topics/show.html.erb`

[HERE](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is a complete guide for routing

Comment: You can use singular resources.